# Can't connect to this network after a while

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking

This question is similar to various other questions. Since I installed Windows 10, with the last 4 wifi networks I used the same problem happens: after a while (several hours, varies) system disconnects and then it cannot connect back until I restart the computer. After the disconnect it behaves strangely: when I try to connect, the wireless network adapter seems to get disabled and reenabled back. Here is a [recording](https://jig-san.me/heap/pic/wifi/wifi.gif) (800Kb) of how this happens. In this state nothing helps — rebooting the router, restarting wireless adapter in device manager manually, deleting network from known — except restarting the PC.

What can cause such an issue? Is there a way to get it connect back without closing running apps?

The device is Qualcomm Atheros AR956x Wireless Network Adapter, with latest drivers.
Windows 10 was installed from iso, not updated from previous version.
Other devices work properly.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem for a while, eventually installed new drivers and it got fixed.

as a workaround what i did was disabling the Network adapter from Devices and then enabling it again. That worked for me.

Otherwise all i can recommend is reinstalling the Drivers or in the end windows 10 again. :S